# select colors in ggsci using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using [ggsci](/questions/tagged/ggsci), but I would like handpick the colors I use.

Say I'm plotting like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsci)
economics_long %>% filter(variable == "psavert" | variable == "uempmed") %>%
   ggplot(aes(date, value01, colour = variable)) +
            geom_line(size = 4)  + scale_color_jama()
```

[image: plot]

but insted of using the first two colors `#374E55FF #DF8F44FF`,

```
show_col(pal_jama("default")(5)); pal_jama("default")(5)
# "#374E55FF" "#DF8F44FF" "#00A1D5FF" "#B24745FF" "#79AF97FF"
```

[image: five]

I could like to use `#00A1D5FF #B24745FF` insted.

```
 pal_jama("default")(5)[3:4] 
 # [1] "#00A1D5FF" "#B24745FF"
```

I can select them using `show_col(pal_jama("default")(5)[3:4])` but how do I select in the `scale_color_jama()` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option can be `scale_color_manual()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsci)
economics_long %>% filter(variable == "psavert" | variable == "uempmed") %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value01, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 4)  + scale_color_manual(values = pal_jama("default")(5)[3:4])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I like it! I am still curios to find out if its possible to select in the `scale_color_jama()` command.

Comment: I don't think so in general. I have always used `scale_color_manual()` for this situation just like in @Duck 's answer/